# Mongodb Indexes getting too much data for sort

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

OK, I am not finding an answer so here is my question...

First off, I have a general mongodb question.  I have a separate db server with mongodb on it.  Do i need to run the rake task to add the indexes on the Rails app server or on the db server?

I keep getting the error "mongo too much data for sort() with no index. add an index or specify a smaller limit"

When I look at the index this is what I get:

```
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "_id" : 1
    },
    "ns" : "app.object_items",
    "name" : "_id_"
},
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "object_id" : 1
    },
    "ns" : "app.object_items",
    "name" : "object_id_1",
    "background" : true
}
```

My relationships are object has_many object_items and object_items belongs to object.

My query that is resulting in the too much data error is:

@object.object_items.where(included: false).sort_by(&:position).first(25)

@object.object_items.count = 54 so we are not talking about a lot of data here.

Is this an issue with the index that I have setup or am I missing something easy?

Thanks in advance.

BR

Comment: I guess you should index the `position` and `included` fields, not ids.

Comment: And you run rake only once after adding the index.

Comment: @Bartosz I have in my model belongs_to :object, index: true.  How do I add the other fields for indexing?

Comment: By adding `index included: 1` and
`index position: 1` to your model?

Comment: Is this working in your case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My query that is resulting in the too much data error is:
>
> @object.object_items.where(included: false).sort_by(&:position).first(25)

According to your list of indexes, you are missing an index that matches your criteria and sort ordering for this query.  I'm presuming that since your `object` has_many `object_items`, the `object_id` is being adding to the `where()` criteria, and you will also need an index on `included` and lastly the `position` field for sorting.

MongoDB (as at 2.4) only uses a single index per query so the expected index to ensure on `object_items` for optimal searches (without the in-memory sort) is:

```
{object_id:1, included:1, position:1}
```

You haven't mentioned what ODM framework you are using with Rails (i.e. Mongoid, MongoMapper, ..), but there should be provision for declaring an index .. or you could ensure it as a one-off via the `mongo` shell.

For example, in Mongoid you can [define an index](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/indexing.html) using the `index` macro in your object_items class:

```
index({object_id:1, included:1, position:1})
```

> @object.object_items.count = 54 so we are not talking about a lot of data here.

The [limit for an in-memory sort](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/v2.4/src/mongo/db/scanandorder.cpp#L28) is 32MB (at least for MongoDB 2.2/2.4).

In your example, I think the `object.object_items` count is misleading as that would only be including the `object_items` matching the `object`.  The actual generated query could be inspecting a larger amount of data.

A better way to understand the query would be to [enable query profiling](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/monitoring/#database-profiling) at level 2 for that database in order to capture the actual queries being generated, and then [`explain()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/) the generated query in the `mongo` shell.